# What's the most concise way to reverse a string using x86 or x86_64 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, micro-optimization, code-size

I'm looking to reverse a string in the shortest amount of assembly code possible.

I can only use SSSE3 extensions or less because of the lack of [Unicorn](https://www.unicorn-engine.org/) support. I've tried accessing ymm & zmm instructions but it breaks every time.

Even though the SSSE3 instructions are more concise, the 16-byte `pshufb` control vector for byte-reversing a 128 bit XMM register still takes up 16 bytes and makes it even longer. I'm open for any ideas but the following are my best attempts.

**I need 32 bytes or less and the smaller the better.** The best I've got so far is 42 but that's when I'm assuming the size of the string inside rdx (or ecx if using x86) is 30.

**Ideally, it would be able to dynamically get the size by checking for a null terminator.**

The string address is sitting inside of rdx (or ecx if using x86).

Additional restriction: no use of stack space.  This block of code has to run without RSP pointing to usable stack memory.

---

Standard x86 / 64 - 42 bytes

```
; get values in registers
mov rax, [rdx]            
mov rbx, [rdx + 8]
mov rcx, [rdx + 16]
mov r8, [rdx + 24]

; swap bytes around
bswap rax
bswap rbx
bswap rcx
bswap r8

; shift it right by 2 because of the nulls
sar r8, 16

; put it back
mov [rdx], r8
mov [rdx + 0x6], rcx
mov [rdx + 0xE], rbx
mov [rdx + 0x16], rax
```

SSE3 - 62 bytes (because of the byte array, otherwise it's 46)

```
movdqu xmm3, [rip + 0x27]
movdqu xmm0, [rdx]
movdqu xmm1, [rdx] + 0x10
pshufb xmm0,xmm3
pshufb xmm1,xmm3


movdqu [rdx], xmm1
movdqu xmm1, [rdx+0x2]
movdqu [rdx], xmm1
movdqu [rdx+0xE], xmm0
hlt

; this would be tacked on to the end of the assembly as the rip + 0x27 value 
\x00\x0F\x0E\x0D\x0C\x0B\x0A\x09\x08\x07\x06\x05\x04\x03\x02\x01
```

Comment: If you to optimize for smallest code-size without regard for performance, a scalar byte loop is almost certainly best (probably with `lodsb` and `stosb` for the forward loads/stores).  I wouldn't be surprised if there's already a working x86 machine-code answer on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ you can use on a string-reverse question.  See also [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981).  But perhaps you're looking for a balance of size and performance, given your choice of fully-unrolled with 64-bit operand-size or SSSE3.

Comment: Another possible compact trick is `lodsb` and `push rax` in a loop.  Once you reach the end of the string, `pop rax` in a loop and `stosb`.  i.e. use callstack as a LIFO stack data structure to reverse the string (wasting 4x or 8x the storage space vs. an easy in-place swap).  If performance *really* doesn't matter, a separate option for in-place swapping is `xchg` to store + load.  (memory destination `xchg` has an implicit `lock` prefix).

Comment: Here's a 32-byte, x86-64 [`void strrev(char* p)`](https://pastebin.com/Ex5aBKPh) that works on any string length _except_ 0 and obeys the System V ABI. If this was x86, it would use even fewer bytes. Maybe you can figure out how to shoehorn the empty-string test in there somehow.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: that looks like an answer; go ahead and post it IMO.  Hint: 2x `dec reg` is only a good idea in 32-bit code with 1-byte `dec`, not in 64-bit code with 3-byte `dec r64`.  `sub rdi, 2` would be better, same length as `std`/`scasw`/`cld`.  With that 2 byte saving, you'd have room for a `JRCXZ` to skip the loop.  Also, you could drop the REX prefixes on `not ecx` / `shr ecx,1` to assume string lengths less than 4GiB.

Comment: @PeterCordes The double-`dec` cannot be fused, since only the second `dec` is a target of the `loop`. Thanks for the `jrcxz` tip though, I'll see if I can compact some more with it.

Comment: @PeterCordes Another problem with that code is that OP wants the pointer in `rdx`, and I'm not sure if that's a hard requirement or just incidental to his current solutions.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't use `jrcxz` in the end, but saved a few bytes by avoiding computing `~strlen() >> 1` and replaced the loop test by a pointer comparison `src <= dst`.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: you can copy a 64-bit register in 2 bytes with `push`/`pop` instead of mov.  push/pop have a default operand-size of 64-bit regardless of a REX prefix.

Comment: @PeterCordes In this context, can I assume I have a stack and `rsp` is set appropriately? I guess OP could answer that question.

Comment: As interesting and sucky as it may be, the Unicorn script itself doesn't have a stack mapped out.  @PeterCordes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following 31 bytes of x86-64 assembler code for `void strrev(char* p)` will reverse a string of any length (including the empty string) in-place, using nothing but the base instruction set.

However, the routine requires the pointer to the string in register `rdi` (in agreement with the System V ABI), not `rdx`. A `mov rdi, rdx` would cost 3 bytes. Also, due to use of two implicitly-locked `xchg`, performance is going to be awful.

The small size is in part due to creative use of the single-byte `stosb`/`lodsb` instructions' side-effects of reading and incrementing/decrementing `rdi` and `rsi` respectively depending on the Direction Flag, which can be set and cleared by means of single-byte instructions `std`/`cld`.

If the code were x86-32 or could limit itself to strings < 4GB, a few bytes of extra savings can be had.

```
0000000000000000 <strrev>:
   0:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
   2:   48 8d 48 ff             lea    rcx,[rax-0x1]
   6:   48 89 fe                mov    rsi,rdi
   9:   f2 ae                   repnz scas al,BYTE PTR es:[rdi]
   b:   48 83 ef 02             sub    rdi,0x2
   f:   48 39 f7                cmp    rdi,rsi
  12:   7e 0a                   jle    1e <strrev+0x1e>
  14:   86 07                   xchg   BYTE PTR [rdi],al
  16:   86 06                   xchg   BYTE PTR [rsi],al
  18:   fd                      std
  19:   aa                      stos   BYTE PTR es:[rdi],al
  1a:   fc                      cld
  1b:   ac                      lods   al,BYTE PTR ds:[rsi]
  1c:   eb f1                   jmp    f <strrev+0xf>
  1e:   c3                      ret
```

Answer (score 2):

The most concise way to reverse a string is to define "string" as a 1-byte "direction and length" byte followed by up to 127 bytes of characters. This allows you to reverse the string with a single `neg byte [rdx]` instruction (which only costs 2 bytes!).

Example (for NASM):

```
myString:
    db myString.end - myString.start
.start:
    db "Hello World!"
.end:

;Reverse a string
;
;Input
; rdx   Address of string to reverse

reverseString:
    neg byte [rdx]
    ret
```

Of course you'd have to write other routines to handle this string format. For example:

```
;Print a string
;
;Input
; rsi   Address of string to print

printString:
    movsz rcx,byte [rsi]    ;rcx = "direction and length" value
    inc rsi
    cmp rcx,0
    jg .l1
    je .done
    std
    neg rcx
.l1:
    lodsb
    call printChar          ;Print the character in AL
    loop .l1
    cld
.done:
    ret

;Get length of a string (in bytes)
;
;Input
; rsi   Address of string
;
;Output
; rcx   Length of string

getStringLength:
    movsz rcx,byte [rsi]    ;rcx = "direction and length" value
    cmp rcx,0
    jge .l1
    neg rcx
.l1:
    ret
```

Comment: I'm not finding any examples. Have you done this before? If so, how is this generally laid out?

Comment: @kr1tzb1tz: I've never needed to reverse a string. Added some example code anyway.. :-)